# SignalR does not return a "Not Authorized" error if the authorization for a certain Hub method fails

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

My Hub configuration is as follows:

```
var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration
{
    EnableDetailedErrors = true, // but still no detailed errors!
    EnableJSONP = true
};
```

Access restriction works as expected. But what I get in the browser is the error `1000 "There was an error invoking Hub method 'xy'."`

What I need to see in the browser is something like `"You are not authorized to invoke Hub method 'xy'."`

Access restriction (`SignalRAuthorizeAttribute` extends `AuthorizeAttribute`):

```
[SignalRAuthorize(ApplicationName = "abc", RequiredRole = UserRole.Manager)]
public X MyHubMethod() { ... }
```

Since the use of `EnableDetailedErrors` is officially discouraged, I prefer a solution without enabling this flag.

Comment: does this happen as well if you use `AuthorizeAtribute` instead of `SignalRAuthorizeAttribute` ?

Comment: I must extend `AuthorizeAttribute` because otherwise I cannot override `UserAuthorized`.